# Which road bike is better?

Tags: road-bike, compatibility

I am looking for a used road bike and came across two of comparable prices. Which is better and are they are good deals?  Both have low mileage and both are in great shape. 2013 Trek Madone 5.1 or 2015 Cannondale SE. asking price for Trek is $1300 and $1200 for Cannondale.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in The Velodrome.

Comment: Neither.  For that amount, you should be able to get a decent brand-new carbon fiber road bike with an 11-speed 105 R7000 groupset.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You inherently assume carbon fiber and 11 speeds are good things. I would pay a huge amount of money to have let's say steel in frame and fork instead of carbon fiber, and a huge amount of money to have let's say 8 speeds instead of 11.

Comment: @juhist Huh?  Where did 8-speed and steel come from?  The question mentions two used, aged 10-speed carbon fiber road bikes that cost about the same as a present-day brand-new 11-speed carbon fiber road bike.  Sure, there might be some advantages for a steel frame, but 8-speed on a road bike?  That was cutting edge more than three decades ago.  But neither is relevant when comparing relatively recent carbon fiber road bikes.

Comment: Red ones are always faster !  Don't take the question closure personally - instead try asking in [chat] which is more free-form